# Shapes not showing in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, paint

I am trying to make one simple paint application in Java but not able to make actions on buttons, now my window is showing with options but how I need to write code to perform action after clicking on shapes drop-down. Please help

Code:

```
    package simplepaint;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawingFrame extends JFrame {
    JButton loadButton,  saveButton, drawButton;
    JComboBox colorList, shapesList;
    JTextField parametersTextField;

    DrawingFrame() {
        super("Drawing Application");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.setRollover(true);

        toolbar.add(loadButton=new JButton("Load"));
        toolbar.add(saveButton=new JButton("Save"));

        toolbar.addSeparator();

        toolbar.add(drawButton=new JButton("Draw"));

        toolbar.addSeparator();
        toolbar.addSeparator();

        toolbar.add(new JLabel("Shape"));
        shapesList=new JComboBox(new String[] { "Circle", "Rectangle", "Line","Triangle" });
        toolbar.add(shapesList);

        toolbar.addSeparator();

        toolbar.add(new JLabel("Parameters"));
        toolbar.add(parametersTextField=new JTextField());

        toolbar.add(new JLabel("Color "));
        colorList=new JComboBox(new String[] { "black", "red", "blue",
                "green", "yellow", "orange", "pink", "magenta", "cyan",
                "lightGray", "darkGray", "gray", "white" });
        toolbar.add(colorList);

        getContentPane().add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
    class DrawPane extends JPanel{
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 200);
       }
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        DrawingFrame frame = new DrawingFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help -- how? You've not asked a specific question but rather have posted unexplained code and given broad requirements. Most of us here will read this question as, "please implement this program functionality for me", and that's not going to go over well. Instead you should show your attempt to implement the functionality, and then if your attempt doesn't work, ask a *specific* question about what's not working or what you don't understand.

Comment: Note your DrawPane is never added to anything -- so it will never draw anything. You have to add it to your JFrame to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

It shows two common ways to do custom painting.

1. store objects to paint in an `ArrayList`
2. paint directly to a `BufferedImage`.

The examples show how to draw a Rectangle with a specified color.

It should be relatively simple to modify the code to draw circles and lines, since they also only require a start and end point.

Drawing the triangle will be more complicated.

Comment: I checked your code their I am able to draw the rectangle only if I want to add more option to select for shapes how I can add?

Comment: @Nayank: by understanding the code and adapting it to your needs. Camickr, methinks that you are answering the question of a help vampire.

Comment: @Nayank, add your combo box and then in the painting code you add and few if statements. If rectangle, draw rectangle. if circle draw circle etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is to create an `ActionListener` so that when the button is clicked, you execute a callback.  In your constructor, you can do something like:

```
    drawButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    });
```

and you'll notice in stdout each time you click the draw button, 'hello' will print.

See @camickr's answer for how to actually do the work of drawing your shapes.